# PHP/MySQL encoding problems. â�� instead of certain characters

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, character-encoding, collation

I have come across some problems when inputting certain characters into my mysql database using php. What I am doing is submitting user inputted text to a database. I cannot figure out what I need to change to allow any kind of character to be put into the database and printed back out through php as it's suppose to.

My MySQL collation is: latin1_swedish_ci

Just before I send the text to the database from my form I use mysql_real_escape_string() on the data.

Example below

this text:

```
â��People are just as happy as they make up their minds to be.â��
â�� Abraham Lincoln
```

is suppose to look like this:

```
“People are just as happy as they make up their minds to be.”
― Abraham Lincoln
```

Comment: Why are you not using a UTF-8 collation?

Comment: Latin1 is not UTF-8. So it's no surprise that characters which are not covered by latin1 like `“` and `―` are Mojibake'd.

Comment: latin1 is I guess the default, and I never, and still don't really understand which collations are the best to use, so I've always used this. I have tried UTF-8 collation before but it didn't seem to fix the problem

Comment: That's because it's not the *whole* solution. Your entire program from tip to stern needs to use UTF-8.

Comment: Note that table collation is not the same as table charset. The collation merely definies the sorting order (usually locale-dependent, such as Swedish as you've initially there) of the characters. So even if you try to use table collation of UTF-8, it won't accept UTF-8 characters if you don't use a table charset of UTF-8.

Comment: Well how would I change my entire site to utf-8? As far as I'm aware I haven't defined any sort of it, except my meta is: <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

Comment: Read the PHP/MySQL manual for clues. That HTML meta tag is by the way only used when the enduser saves the webpage to local disk file system and then opens it from there by `file://` URL. It's not used when the page is served over `http://`. Instead, the real HTTP response header is been consulted. See also HTML spec chapter 5.2.2.

Comment: I have looked at the manual with little luck of finding what I need to do.

Comment: Had to look up mojibake on wikipedia - which had this amazing, amazing story linked on the article - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Letter_to_Russia_with_krokozyabry.jpg - as coders, you should _all_ read this, and learn why unicode is important :)

Comment: Would altering the table's collation mess up something in the columns?  I realize it's not going to bring back the original characters, but I don't want it to mess up other characters as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As mentioned by others, you need to convert to UTF8 from end to end if you want to support "special" characters. This means your web page, PHP, mysql connection and mysql table. The web page is fairly simple, just use the meta tag for UTF8. Ideally your headers would say UTF8 also.

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Set your PHP to use UTF8. Things would probably work anyway, but it's a good measure to do this:

```
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
mb_http_output('UTF-8');
mb_http_input('UTF-8');
```

For mysql, you want to convert your table to UTF8, no need to export/import.

```
ALTER TABLE table_name CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8
```

You can, and should, configure mysql to default utf8. But you can also run the query:

```
 SET NAMES UTF8
```

as the first query after establishing a connection and that will "convert" your database connection to UTF8.

That should solve all your character display problems.

Comment: The meta tag is ignored when the page is served over HTTP. It's only used when the page is opened from local disk file system. The headers have a bigger importance than the meta tag.

Comment: Thanks I will go through and do all of this. Even though I had done most of these steps already without success, or complete success,

Comment: You only need to miss 1 step to have it fail. The SET NAMES UTF8 query is very important if mysql isn't configure to be fully utf8.

Comment: Okay thanks, I have gone ahead and set these things in my php, however things don't seem to be working. I did also run that alter table code in my database as well. I have a file called connect.php that gets included with every page that I make a mysql query to and from, this page is where i connect and select my database. I added these lines to it without any success:  mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");   
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
mb_http_output('UTF-8');
mb_http_input('UTF-8');

Comment: Hmm actually it appears that I've got it working correctly as far is insertying the data to MYSQL, I think this because in the database is no longer has all that junk from the characters, it just has the actual characters showing as they should. The problem now looks to be echoing the data back out onto the page, I have tried utf8_decode but that doesn't really seem to do anything, so hmm I'm stumped with this part.

Comment: Are you running SET NAMES 'utf8' every time you establish a database connection? You need to set the connection to UTF8. If the connection is dropped, when you reconnect you need to set the connection to UTF8 again. You should be using PDO or mysqli, not mysql_query.

Comment: `SET NAMES UTF8` was the solution for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

The likeliest cause of the problem is that the database *connection* is set to `latin1` but you are feeding it text encoded in UTF-8. The simplest way to solve this is to convert your input into what the client expects:

```
$quote = iconv("UTF-8", "WINDOWS-1252//TRANSLIT", $quote);
```

(What MySQL calls `latin1` is windows-1252 in the rest of the world.) Note that many characters, such as the quotation dash U+2015 that you use there, cannot be represented in this encoding and will be converted into something else. Ideally you should change the column encoding to `utf8`.

An alternative solution: set the database connection to `utf8`. It doesn't matter how the columns are encoded: MySQL internally converts text from the connection encoding into the storage encoding, you can keep the columns as `latin1` if you want to. (If you do, the quotation dash U+2015 will be turned into a question mark `?` because it's not in `latin1`)

How to set the connection encoding depends on what library you are using: if you use the deprecated MySQL library it's mysql_set_charset, if MySQLi it's mysqli_set_charset, if PDO add `encoding=utf8` to the DSN.

If you do this you'll have set the page encoding to UTF-8 with the Content-Type header. 
Otherwise you would be having the same problem with the browser: feeding it text encoded in UTF-8 when it's expecting something else:

```
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
```

Comment: I have done and tried everything that one of the answers has suggested (Brent's), and haven't been able to get that to work, but I have tried using mysql_set_charset("utf8"); (which is which library I use), but that didn't fix things either. I have gone through everything without any luck :\

Comment: Hmm actually it appears that I've got it working correctly as far is insertying the data to MYSQL, I think this because in the database is no longer has all that junk from the characters, it just has the actual characters showing as they should. The problem now looks to be echoing the data back out onto the page, I have tried utf8_decode but that doesn't really seem to do anything, so hmm I'm stumped with this part.

Comment: Check which encoding the web browser uses to display the page - is it the one it should be? Are you setting the Content Type header?

Comment: Does it still show â�� instead of a curly quote, or just a �?

Comment: Oh damn, it was my using of "htmlentities()" on the returned string that caused that.. hmm, well I'm quite sure I need to use that function, or a similar one still, without wrecking the utf8 characters.

Comment: If you are worried about XSS you can use `htmlspecialchars`, it won't touch Unicode characters. If you want to use `htmlentities` you have use the encoding argument.

Comment: Yes, I found the encoding arguments for htmlentities and have since applied them to each of my entities and all is working perfectly now, thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 1):

The solutions provided are helpful *if* starting from scratch. Putting all possible connections to UTF-8 is indeed the safest. UTF-8 is the most used charset on the net for a variety of reasons.

Some suggestions and a word of warning:

- **copy** the tables you want to sanitize with a unique prefix (tmp_)
- although your db-connection is forced to utf8, check you General Settings collation, change to **utf8_bin** if that was not done yet
- you need to run this on the local server
- the funny char error is mostly due to mixing LATIN1 with UTF-8 configurations. This solution is designed for this. It could work with other used char-sets that LATIN1 but I haven't checked this
- **check** these tmp_tables extensively before copying back to the original

Builds the 2 array needed for the magic:

```
$chars = get_html_translation_table(HTML_ENTITIES, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
$LATIN1 = $UTF8 = array();
while (list($key,$val) = each ($chars)) {
    $UTF8[] = $key;
    $LATIN1[] = $val;
}
```

Now build up the routines you need: (tables->)rows->fields and at each field call

```php
$row[$field] = mysql_real_escape_string(str_replace($LATIN1 , $UTF8 , $row[$field]));
$q[] = "$field = '{$row[$field]}'";
```

Finally build up and send the query:

```php
mysql_query("UPDATE $table SET " . implode(" , " , $q) . " WHERE id = '{$row['id']}' LIMIT 1");
```

Answer (score 0):

change the MySQL collation to utf8_unicode_ci or utf8_general_ci, including the table and the database.

Comment: Thanks, I have done this now and it doesn't seem to have any effect on the issue :\

Comment: Of course not, the collation merely definies the sorting order of the characters. E.g. `á` before `ä` or the other way round. It doesn't define the charset actually used by the table. For that you'd need to change the table charset.

Comment: I don't know if this will be helpful or not, but I used these information to change the collation to binary as I wanted to keep each characters value and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set your database in utf-8 yes. There is many ways to do it. By changin the config file, via phpmyadmin or by calling php function (sorry memory blank) right before insert and update the mysql.

Unfortunately, i think you will have to re-enter any data you entered before.

One thing you also need to know, from personnal experience, make sure all table with relation have the same collation or you won'T be able to JOIN them.

as reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/charset-syntax.html

Also, i can be a apache setting. We've experienced the same issue on 'free-hosting' server as well as on my brother's server. Once switched to another server, all the charater's became neat. Verfiy you apache setting, sorry but i can't bting more light on apache's config.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of everything you just need to follow these two points, every problem regarding special languages characters will be resolved.

1- You need to define the collation of your table to be utf8_general_ci.

2- define `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">` in the HTML after head tag.

2- You need to define the `mysql_set_charset('utf8',$link_identifier);` in the file where you made connection with the database and right after the selection of database like 'mysql_select_db' use this 'mysql_set_charset' this will allow you to add and retrieve data properly in what ever the language it is.

Answer (score 0):

If your text has been encoded and decoded with the wrong encoding and so the mojibake is actually "solidified" into unicode characters, then the solutions mentioned so far won't work. I ended up having success with the `ftfy` Python package to automatically detect/fix mojibake:

- https://github.com/LuminosoInsight/python-ftfy
- https://pypi.org/project/ftfy/
- https://ftfy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

```
>>> import ftfy
>>> print(ftfy.fix_encoding("(à¸‡'âŒ£')à¸‡"))
(ง'⌣')ง
```

Hopefully this helps people who are in a similar situation.