# What is the usefulness of mb_http_output() given that the output encoding is typically fixed by other means?

Tags: character-encoding

All over the Internet, including in stackoverflow, it is suggested to use mb_http_input('utf-8') to have PHP works in the UTF-8 encoding. For example, see [PHP/MySQL encoding problems. â�� instead of certain characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12984841/php-mysql-encoding-problems-a-instead-of-certain-characters). On the other hand, the PHP manual says that we cannot fix the input encoding within the PHP script and that mb_http_input is only a way to query what it is, not a way to set it. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/mbstring.http.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-httpetinput.php . Ok, this was just a clarification of the context before the question. It seems to me that there is a lot of redundant commands in Apache + PHP + HTML to control the conversion from the input encoding to the  internal encoding and finally to the output encoding. I don't understand the usefulness of this.  For example, if the original input encoding from some external HTTP client is EUC-JP and I set the internal encoding to UTF-8, then PHP would have to make the conversion. Am I right? If I am right, why would I set an input encoding in php.ini (instead of just passing the original one) given that it would be next immediately converted to the utf-8 internal encoding anyway?  A similar question hold for the output. In all my htpp files, I use a meta tag with charset=utf-8. So, the output HTTP encoding is fixed. Moreover, in PHP.ini, I can set the default_charset that will appear in the HTTP header to utf-8. Why would I bother to use mb_http_output('uft-8') when the final output encoding is already fixed. To sum up, can someone give me a practical concrete example where mb_http_output('uft-8') is clearly necessary and cannot be replaced by more usual commands that are often inserted by default in editors such as Dreamweaver?

Comment: Very often answers dealing with character encodings on Stack Overflow are partly or completely wrong or the author of an answer clearly doesn't understand and by blind luck stumbled upon something that looks like it's doing something correctly but in fact isn't. There are very few answerers getting it right reliably.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

These two options are just about the worst idea the PHP designers ever had, and they had plenty of bad ideas when it comes to encodings.

To convert strings *to* a specific encoding, one has to know what encoding one is converting *from*. Incoming data is often in an undeclared encoding; the server just receives some binary data, it doesn't know what encoding it represents. You should declare what encoding you expect the browser to send by setting the `accept-charset` attribute on forms; doing that is no guarantee that the browser will do so and it doesn't make PHP know what encoding to expect though.

The same goes for output; PHP strings are just byte arrays, they do not have an associated encoding. I have no idea how PHP thinks it knows how to convert arbitrary strings to a specific encoding upon input *or* output.

You should handle this manually, and it's really easy to do anyway: declare to clients what encoding you expect, *check* whether input is in the correct encoding using `mb_check_encoding` (not `_detect encoding` or some such, just *check*), reject invalid input, take care to keep everything in the same encoding within the whole application flow. I.e., ideally you have **no conversion** whatsoever in your app.

If you *do* need to convert at any point, make it a Unicode sandwich: convert input from the expected encoding to UTF-8 or another Unicode encoding on input, convert it back to desired output encoding upon output. Whenever you need to convert, make sure you know what you're converting *from*. You cannot magically "make all strings UTF-8" with one declaration.

Comment: What about this standard : http://www.w3.org/International/O-HTTP-charset.en.php ?  It is not useful?

Comment: @Dominic108 Sure it's useful. It declares *to the browser* what encoding the page is supposedly in. You *need* to set this. This doesn't change anything what I wrote above though. Maybe see [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/) for more information.

Comment: I noticed that IE 9 would not include the charset in the header that it sends, even if I specify  accept-charset="UTF-8" in the form. I am not saying this in opposition to what you wrote. Just noticing it.

Comment: Exactly, which is precisely why `mbstring.http_input` is so unreliable and hence pointless. You could make a case for `mbstring.http_output` as helper for the Unicode sandwich, but the fact that it doesn't allow simple and clear configuration about what encoding to convert *from* makes it unreliable at best as well.

Comment: mbstring.http_input is a runtime configuration whereas mb_http_input(), which seems to be its function counterpart,  is just a way to query the encoding. This is in itself confusing. Anyway, in both cases, I understand what you mean. How can they know what is the encoding, if the conventions are not used by IE, etc.

Comment: Regarding `mb_http_input()`: any function that says "***detects*** encoding" is useless by definition. You can *guess* an encoding or you can *read metadata encoding declarations*, you cannot *detect* encodings. :)

Comment: From the current `mbstring` maintainer, having just seen this 10 years after it was posted: Bravo! I would like to put what you have written here in the PHP manual!