# "â€" character in front and at the end of my string in the MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

-I've made a select input with options,
-I've given each option a value="something".
The problem is that in the database the submited value appears like "â€somethingâ€", instead of "something".
I've made research and I've putted :

```
$link= mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER , DB_PASS);
mysql_set_charset('UTF8',$link);
```

& already had:

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

In my database the collation is of type:"utf8_unicode_ci" for all columns

What is the problem then ?

Comment: I'm guessing that is a quote. May be caused by different encoding during write operations.

Comment: Is the table itself set to utf-8. See answer to this too : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12984841/php-mysql-encoding-problems-%C3%A2-instead-of-certain-characters

Comment: Could be due to your inserting/retrieving code or a copy and paste from some other character set. Can we see the code?

Comment: @Phil_1984_ which code , the HTML , or the PHP ?

Comment: @PaulF I've applied the code answer in that question you sent me, same thing...

Comment: @Phil_1984_ I've wrote the options in word and after that copy them in the editor, but my editor is set to UTF-8 encoding without BOM, so when I saved it, it overwrote the paste/encoding... that's not it  -.-

Comment: And what is the stupid thing is that a have 2 radio inputs with values and they also have underscore "_" and they are perfectly fine, and here a have only text and this appears: “â€” o.O

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the data in your database was not written there in UTF8. So you are getting a mismatch of encodings.

Relevant SO question here: ["â€™" showing on page instead of " ' "](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2477452/%C3%A2%E2%82%AC-showing-on-page-instead-of)

Answer (score 0):

My bad,
I copied from Microsoft Word(because there is where I wrote the code ONLY TO ORDER IT ASCENDING BY LETTERS) plese don't BOOOOO!!!
So the code was like:

```
<option value=”something”>something</option>
```

the answer is:

```
"something"!=”something” ; " != ”
```

That was the problem :D

Comment: Yep so in the absence of any proper " those weird quote characters were considered part of the value data by the browser that submitted the data to the database.